# When I save a PySpark DataFrame with saveAsTable in AWS EMR Studio, where does it get saved?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-emr, aws-emr-studio

I can save a dataframe using `df.write.saveAsTable('tableName')` and read the subsequent table with `spark.table('tableName')` but I'm not sure where the table is actually getting saved?

Comment: you can probably check the definition of your table to see where the data are stored.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored under the default location of your database.

You can get the location by running the following spark sql query:

`spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED tableName")`

You can find the `Location` under the `# Detailed Table Information` section.
Please find a sample output below:
[image]

Comment: How does the output looks like ? Maybe you can give an idea ?

Comment: I added a sample in the answer